# Creating own Smarty variable like $smarty.session

Tags: php, session, smarty

So I am using a custom PHP Session handler (One that kinda works like the one in Laravel if you're familiar with the framework), which don't register to the `$_SESSION` superglobal, so I can't use `{$smarty.session.some_data}` to access it.

However, in my Smarty template I still would like to retrieve values stored in the session without needing to assign the value manually to a Smarty variable all the time. What would be the best way to create a way to access my session data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The more time I am wasting time trying to fix "limitations" like this the more I am starting to wonder why I am still using Smarty as a whole. Really. If you can just write a dispatcher which is smart enough to bring the variables from a controller scope to a view scope, why bother? I am reading page after page about custom Smarty functions when a simple `<?= Session::get('message'); ?>` does exactly the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there's no way to use syntax `$smarty.yourarray.data` but this syntax is used for global array ($_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE, $_SERVER).

However you can access static class in the same method as in PHP.

Assume you have the following class in PHP file:

```
class Session
{
    public static function get($data) {
        if (is_int($data)) {
            return $data * 3;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Now, you don't need to assign anything to Smarty.

When in Smarty file you want to access this class method you simply need to use:

```
{Session::get('something')}<br />
{Session::get(2)}
```

And you will get result:

```
something
6
```

as expected.

So you don't have to do anything to access this class (no modifiers/functions, you even don't need to assign this class).

However let's assume you have your Session class in namespace:

```
<?php

//session.php

namespace MySession;

class Session
{
    public static function get($data) {
        if (is_int($data)) {
            return $data * 3;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

If you want to this static class inside Smarty you will need to register your class:

```
require ('session.php');
$smarty->registerClass('Session', 'MySession\Session');
```

to make it work (you cannot use namespace in TPL file as far as I know).

Comment: Hm, interesting! Didn't know it was possible to call static methods like this without needing to assign something. That is way easier than I had imagined.

Comment: @Gladen Not everything in Smarty is so obvious, even in documentation I think there is no necessary information